# Convergence of series of function compositions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is there an example of a function $f$ such that $f’(0)=1$ and $\sum f^n(x)$ is finite for any $x$? Here $f^n =f\circ\dots\circ f$ performed $n$ times.

Comment: Can you precise your attempts ?

Comment: @EDX I was in a cab, bored and thought about convergence of series of iterated $\log$. Well, quickly I've realized that I'd need $x\mapsto\log(1+x)$. Then I've realized that convergence of such iterated series may depend on the derivative at $0$ given the equivalence test. So if the derivative is $< 1$ we have convergence, if it is $>1$ we have divergence. So I wondered what happens in the case it is exactly $1$. I've realized I haven't ever seen anything on this topic, yet question seemed interesting to me so I've decided to ask it straight away. I only had a phone, hence the laconic style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, we shall prove that $f(x)=x-x\sqrt{|x|}e^{-x^2}$ works.

**First, we study the function $f$ :**

For every $x \neq 0$, one has
$$\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = 1-\sqrt{|x|}e^{-x^2} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{x \to0} 1$$

so $f$ is differentiable with $f'(0)=1$.

Moreover, it is easy to see that $f(x)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x=0$, and that $f(x) \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow x \geq 0$.

Finally, let's notice that for $x \geq 0$, one has $0 \leq f(x) \leq x$.

**Secondly, we study the series :**

Now, let $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and let's define the sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by $u_n=f^n(x)$.

Since the function $f$ is odd, one can assume that $x \geq 0$. The interval $[0,+\infty)$ being stable by $f$, then $u_n \geq 0$ for every $n$. One deduce thet $0 \leq f(u_n) \leq u_n$, i.e. that $0 \leq u_{n+1} \leq u_n$. So $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing, and bounded below, so it converges to a limit $l$, which must satisfy $f(l)=l$, so $l=0$.

Since $u_n \geq 0$, one deduces also that $u_{n+1} = u_n - u_n^{3/2}e^{-u_n^2}$.

Then, one has
\begin{align*}
u_{n+1}^{-1/2} - u_n^{-1/2} &= \left(  u_n - u_n^{3/2}e^{-u_n^2} \right)^{-1/2} - u_n^{-1/2} \\
& = u_n^{-1/2} \left[ \left(  1 - u_n^{1/2}e^{-u_n^2} \right)^{-1/2} - 1\right]\\
& = u_n^{-1/2} \left[  1 + \dfrac{1}{2} u_n^{1/2}e^{-u_n^2}  + O \left( u_ne^{-2u_n^2} \right)- 1\right]\\
& =   \dfrac{1}{2} e^{-u_n^2}  + O \left( u_n^{1/2}e^{-2u_n^2} \right)  \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \to+\infty} \dfrac{1}{2} 
\end{align*}

By Stolz-Cesaro, one gets that
$$u_n^{-1/2} \sim \dfrac{n}{2}$$

so $u_n \sim \dfrac{4}{n^2}$, and so the series $\sum u_n$ converges.